# Is there a way to keep costs low with AWS Amplify DataStore @searchable directive?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-elasticsearch

I'm using AWS Amplify DataStore to create an offline first notes app. To be able to search my notes I just add the `@searchable`directive to the Schema and my DB documents are streamed to an AWS elastic service.

But, my initial test of this ended up costing me a lot of money. My dev project went from $2/month to $30/month just by adding the ES node. There doesn't seem to be a way to downscale the service from the AWS console.

Does anyone know of a way to not pay $30/month for 12kb of data in ES?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the [documentation](https://docs.amplify.aws/cli/graphql-transformer/directives#searchable) the `@searchable` directive sets up an ElasticSearch instance and streams data there. Moreover, t2.micro instances are not compatible - probably why you can't downscale.

There are a number of issues on the AWS Amplify Github repo similar to your question - see [this](https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-cli/issues/3860) and [this](https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-cli/issues/3561).

I am in a similar boat and debating setting up a small server running [MeiliSearch](https://github.com/meilisearch/MeiliSearch) or migrating to [Algolia](https://algolia.com/).

FWIW, the AppSync documentation search is powered by Algolia :-).

Answer (score 3):

I also found the cost of Elasticsearch to be annoying when developing my MVP so I created the [graphql-algolia-transformer](https://github.com/thefinnomenon/graphql-algolia-transformer) which allows you to use Algolia instead for your searches which has a decent free quota and is pay per record/request from there.

Comment: This is great @thefinnomenon!

Answer (score 2):

If your schema isn't so complicated, then you can just use `filter`.

Let's assume you has got schema.graphql:

```
type Person @model {
  id: ID!
  firstName: String!
  lastName: String!
}
```

Then you can search by query:

```
listPersons(filter: {
  or: [
    { firstName: { contains: "Alex" } },
    { lastName: { contains: "Alex" } }
  ]
}) {
  items {
    id
    firstName
    lastName
  }
}
```

But if your search queries are more complicated you need to use ElasticSearch.

https://docs.amplify.aws/cli/graphql-transformer/examples#blog-queries

Comment: Just a caution, the listPersons runs a Scan on the database and then only filters what it gets, as your data scales the scans become a very heavy operation to run on all your data. 

https://youtu.be/VG2XWoD-rS0?t=460